# Group associated to multiplicative group

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, formal-power-series

Let formal multiplocative group be $$\mathbb{G}_m(X,Y) = X + Y + XY$$

Let $R$ be a complete local ring, and $M$ be its maximal ideal.

According to Silverman's 'the arithmetic of elliptic curves', group associated to formal multiplicative group, $\mathbb{G}_m(M) $ is $1＋M$ with group law multiplication.

But the book also reads group associated to formal groups $F（M）$ is $M$ as a set.

But $M$ and $1＋M$ is not the same set. What am I missing?

Comment: The formal multiplicative group on $M$ is $M$ with "shifted multiplication" that makes it a disguised version of $1 + M$: for $x$ and $y$ in $M$, $x+y+xy = (1+x)(1+y) - 1$, so when you give $M$ the formal group law from $\mathbb G_m$, you're really working with $1+M$ but subtract 1 from everything so you make the identity $0$ rather than $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then, my understanding ; M is not equal to 1＋M  as a set, but its group structure is isomorphic to （1＋M）×  with multiplication of R. This understanding is ok?

Comment: The isomorphism of $1+M$ (under multplication) is not with $M$ and its additive group structure, but with $M$ and its shifted group structure from $1+M$: $(x,y) \mapsto (1+x)(1+y) - 1 = x+y+xy$ for $x, y \in M$. This new group structure on $M$ *need not* be isomorphic to $M$ under addition, e.g., additively there are no nontrivial elements of finite order in $2\mathbf Z_2$, but $1+2\mathbf Z_2$ has $-1$ as an element of finite order under multiplication.  (For odd prime $p$, $1+p\mathbf Z_p$ under multiplication is isomorphic to $p\mathbf Z_p$ under addition using the $p$-adic logarithm.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Then, my understanding; M with formal multiplicative group structure is isomorphic to multiplicative group M with R's multiplication, of course M and 1＋M is not same as a set, but as group structure （M with formal multiplicative group structure, 1＋M with R's multipliccation）they are same. Is this understanding ok?

Comment: I understood 1＋2Z2 is not isomorphic to Z2, but what is the dirrerence in the case of  1＋pZp and pZp where p is odd prime? pZp does not have non trivial elements of finite order, and 1＋pZp has -1 as order 2 element in the same way as Z2. What am I missing?

Comment: What you write is correct except "isomorphic to multiplicative group $M$ with $R$'s multiplication" should be  "isomorphic to multiplicative group $1+M$ with $R$'s multiplication".

Comment: For all $p$, the $p$-adic logarithm converges on $1 + p\mathbf Z_p$.  For $p > 2$, the $p$-adic exponential converges on $p\mathbf Z_p$, but the $2$-adic exponential converges on $4\mathbf Z_2$ and *not* on $2\mathbf Z_2$.  The $p$-adic exponential and logarithm for odd primes  $p$ are inverse isomorphisms between $p\mathbf Z_p$ and $1+p\mathbf Z_p$, while the $2$-adic exponential and logarithm are inverse isomorphisms between $4\mathbf Z_2$ and $1+4\mathbf Z_2$.

Comment: Of course $p^k\mathbf Z_p \cong \mathbf Z_p$ for all $k \geq 1$ (or really all $k \in \mathbf Z$), but $1 + p^k\mathbf Z_p \cong 1 + p\mathbf Z_p$ for all $k \geq 2$ when $p$ is odd while $1 + 2^k\mathbf Z_p \cong 1 + 4\mathbf Z_p \not\cong 1 + 2\mathbf Z_2$ for $k \geq 2$.